# How to utilize multiple Google Cloud TPUs to train a single model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I have been allocated multiple Google Cloud TPUs in the `us-central1-f` region. The machine types are all `v2-8`.

How can I utilize all my TPUs to train a single model?

The `us-central1-f` region [doesn't support pods](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/regions), so using pods doesn't seem like the solution. Even if pods were available, the number of v2-8 units that I have does not match any of the pod TPU slice sizes (16, 64, 128, 256), so I couldn't use them all in a single pod.

Comment: Any specific reason you cannot move to `us-central1-a` which has TPU Pods?

Comment: The TPUs I've been given are specifically for `us-central1-f`. As in, if I move them, I'll have to pay for their usage, as opposed to it being free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot easily do this. If you want to train a single model using multiple TPUs, you would need to have access to a region with TPU Pods. Otherwise you can do the obvious thing: train the same model on different TPUs but with different hyperparameters as a way to do grid search OR you can train multiple weak learners and then manually combine them.

Answer (score 5):

Though I can't find documentation which explicitly answers this question, I have read multiple articles and questions and come to the conclusion that if you are using `v2-8` or `v3-8` TPUs, it is not possible to use multiple of them at a time. You will have to use larger machines like `v2-32` or `v3-32` to ensure you have access to more cores, and the TFRC program does not provide that for free.

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones
- https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/training-on-tpu-pods
- https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/48
- https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/304